# set lua default search path correctly to find required lua module

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake, lua

I have a visual studio project with c++ code calling lua files.

I try to load a lua module but it cannot be find.
If understand correctly, package.path can be set i.a. via LUA_PATH environment variable.
So before running the lua file i call a script with the lines to set the path to the parent folder of the lua module:

`set LUA_PATH=%LUA_PATH%;C:\Users\xyz\lua`

Then in the lua file i try to concat the search path with strings, but doesnt work:

`package.path = package.path .. "./?.lua;"`

edit:
output of `print(package.path)`:

```
;C:\Users\xyz\lua;./?.lua;
```

but i want

```
;C:\Users\xyz\lua\?.lua;
```

edit:
I forgot to the delete the semicolon at the end of LUA_PATH.
Now it works without the package.path line.

Comment: and now `print(package.path)`

Comment: @Mike V. i add print output

Comment: Did the concatenation really add that middle `;` in `;C:\Users\xyz\lua;./?.lua;`? I'd expect this to work: `package.path = package.path .. "\\?.lua;"` (even though I don't understand why you want an empty directory entry first and last in the variable).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo i wrongly added a semicolon in at the end of set LUA_PATH=...

Comment: @Meldryt You added one to the beginning too. What about the middle one that I asked about. Is that really done by the concatenation? What do you get if you do `package.path = package.path .. "\\?.lua;"` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i get ;C:\Users\xyz\lua\?.lua; The first semicolon comes from this part %LUA_PATH%;

Comment: @Meldryt Yes, I know where the first semicolon comes from. You put it there when you did `set LUA_PATH=%LUA_PATH%;C:\Users\xyz\lua` since `LUA_PATH` was empty/unset before. Anyway, you said that you want `;C:\Users\xyz\lua\?.lua;` and isn't that exactly what you got when doing what I suggested?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `set LUA_PATH=%LUA_PATH%;C:\Users\xyz\lua`

That adds a `;` infront of `C:\Users\xyz\lua` unless `LUA_PATH` already contains something. You might want something like this instead:

```
IF DEFINED LUA_PATH (
    set LUA_PATH=%LUA_PATH%;
)
set LUA_PATH=%LUA_PATH%C:\Users\xyz\lua
```

> `package.path = package.path .. "./?.lua;"`

That adds a `;` at the end and also adds `./` where you probably want `\` so try this instead:

```
package.path = package.path .. "\\?.lua"
```